# Why is my "show/hide with cookie" jquery code not working?

Tags: jquery, cookies

Any page on my website has a message in a grey div (#showHideInfoXmas): https://www.bagnboxman.co.uk/product/gusseted-clear-bottle-bags-94-diam-x-420mm/

It's not working!

I want to allow users to close the message and have the website remember their choice.

I have included the cookie jquery plugin - I have even tried moving the script to after the include.

```
$(function() {
  $('#showHideInfoXmasButton').parent().toggle(!$.cookie('divHidden')); // Hide if cookie there
  $('#showHideInfoXmasButton').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().hide();
    $.cookie('divHidden', 'true'); // Remember it was hidden
  });
});

<div id="showHideInfoXmas" style="display: block; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.15); clear: both; width: 100%; padding: 40px 20px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; max-width: 1000px; position: relative;">
  <div id="showHideInfoXmasButton" style="background: white; position: absolute; top: 10px; right: 10px; padding: 10px; color: red;">X</div>
  <h2 style="color: red">IMPORTANT NEWS - Christmas closing, the weather and postage times</h2>
  <p><b>Christmas opening times:</b> on Wednesday, December the 20th at 11am we are closed for our winter break, and re-opening on Wednesday the 3rd January 2018. Any orders placed after 9AM on December the 20th will not be processed until January 3rd at
    the earliest.</p>
  <p><b>Snowfall:</b> Due to the adverse weather conditions and the fact that it is our busiest time of the year, please be aware that any orders placed may take longer than usual to be dispatched. If your order is time-sensitive, please call us on 01295
    788522.
  </p>
  <p><b>Stock levels:</b> Please note: as it is the busiest time of the year for us, our stock levels will be unpredictable, to avoid disappointment please get your orders in as soon as possible!</p>
  <p><b>Postage:</b> As with any other online retailer, this time of the year sees extraordinary stresses on the national and world-wide postage and courrier network and your order may be subject to delays beyond of our control.</p>
  <p>Rest assured; we are working very hard to ensure your orders are despatched as quickly as possible. Thank you for your understanding!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Given the `$ is not a function` error on your site it would appear you have not included jQuery. Also note for the future that all relevant code should be placed *in the question*.

Comment: Im gonna go ahead and try to save your question. Keep in mind the points that Rory made above about including all **relevant code** in your question.

Comment: Sorry Rory, thanks Master Yoda. Will include full code next time. Code wouldn't format so used a gist instead.

I do have jquery included, so not sure why you're seeing that error, Rory?

Comment: @tjcss When you say its not working whats not working exactly? The cookie does not save or JS is throwing errors?

Comment: The div is not hiding, I'm not sure how to check if the cookie is setting?

Comment: Wrap the javascript part in `$(document).ready(function(){ // here })` and see if it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Truth is, I don't really know why it wasn't working, but here is the code that works for me:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  if (typeof Cookies('divhideXMAS') === 'undefined'){
   //no cookie
    jQuery('#showHideInfoXmas').show();
  } else {
  }
  jQuery('#showHideInfoXmasButton').click(function() {
  jQuery(this).parent().hide();
    Cookies.set('divhideXMAS', true);
  });     
 });
```

I then hide the div by default with css.